# SQL: where condition with all

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

user table

```
id : Integer
name: String
```

user_review table

```
user_id: Integer
review: Integer
```

Now, the user record is having many user_review records.

I need to get all users who has `5 review` and `4 review`.

```
SELECT * FROM user JOIN user_review ON user.id = user_review.user_id
 WHERE user_review.review = 5 AND user_review.review = 4
```

Abobe code is retuning empty result.

I tried below code, but, return wrong result

```
SELECT * FROM user JOIN user_review ON user.id = user_review.user_id
 WHERE user_review.review in [5, 4]
```

**Sample data**
Users

```
id name
1  MM
2  EE
```

user_profile

```
user_id, review
1        4
1        5
2        4
2        5
3        4
4        5
```

**Wanted result**

```
id name
1  MM             // user1, having (review4) and (review5)
2  EE             // user2, having (review4) and (review5)
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: please provide sample data and show us what you get and what you expect?

Comment: The second query is what  I would have suggested based on your question. What results did you get and how did they differ from what you want?

Comment: select U.id, U.name from user U inner join user_review R on U.id=R.user_id where review in (4,5) group by (U.id);

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want. All users who have both a review = 4 and a review = 5

```
select * from users 
where exists(select * from user_review where user_id = user.id and review = 4)
and exists(select * from user_review where user_id = user.id and review = 5)
```

Comment: Yes, this is right, but, the query seems complex

Comment: That's some code that will stay in your codebase and not change anymore probably, 3 lines of code for a query is not what I would call "complex". @MERN do you want these values (4 and 5) to be somehow dynamic?

Comment: I guess complexity is in the eye of the beholder.